# Call Azure function from azure cloud service without API key

Tags: azure

Good day,

we created an Azure function which fetches a secret from a key vault. The idea is not to have the secret in the code, as not every developer should be able to authenticate with the application.

However, now I had to include the azure function's *API Key* in code, which (for me) seems like adding just another layer to the problem without actually preventing anyone from accessing the secret (the developer would just need to call the function).

I wonder: **Is there any possibility to allow calling an Azure Function from a cloud service without an API key**? I'd argue this *should* be possible, as both is living in azure itself. However, I already tried exactly this: Calling the function (from the cloud service) without key, nevertheless this just says *forbidden*.

Comment: In term of auth flow, you can use oauth to authenticate from cloud service to az fuction. but not sure to understand the problem ? what kind of access does developpers have ? are you talking about developpers of the cloud service or function app ?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Not anonymous, but I'd allow calls from code hosted on the cloud service itself without API key.

Comment: @Thomas The developer's of the actual code base hosted on the cloud service. They should not gain access to the application secret.

Comment: I mean in a dev envrionment hey should have full control ?

Comment: @Thomas the only instance needing full access is the production environment. In development, no one should.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your point, dont you have different secrets for prod and dev ?  Anyway you can do it using OAuth but then your cloud service will need to store the clien_id/secret also so not sure what you prefer ? If all your envrionments are isolated it should be fine